# True Enterprise Reporting

Tags: reporting

Has anyone done true enterprise reporting - if so, was it home grown or purchased?  What I am talking about is creating a reporting portal that allows a single entry point to any reporting engine's results.  I would like a single browser based place for my global users to go to get reports.

Each locale may have a different infrastructure built for business intelligence - but I want them to go to the central place to view and execute reports in the same way everyone else does - regardless of bi infrastructure.  A locale would map their data - their BI solution to the reporting portal - and be able to use the reporting portal to view, execute and export report resuts with the same look and feel as everyone else in the organization.

I think it is unrealistic of reporting vendors/industry to think a large global organization is going to standardize on a single bi solution - it is more likely our scenario.  Many bi tools - the right tool for the right job - and a vision to have a reporting portal that brings together everything and places controls on look/feel/metrics/processes. So, has anyone done true enterprise reporting - if so, was it home grown or purchased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We rolled our own web reporting portal that hooks up to Business Objects, Crystal etc. it manages report parameters, scheduling etc and gives a consistent UI. Sure it has it's problems but we couldn't find an off the shelf solution that came anywhere close.

Comment: any chance we can have a call to talk through lessons learned ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a SharePoint 2007 presentation on this topic. You may want to look deeper into SharePoint.